# Find treshold to separate two classes based on single predictor

Tags: classification, threshold, univariate

I have a binary output variable (not healthy, healthy) that I want to classify. I found based on univariate analysis that one of my independent predictors already tells apart both classes perfectly.

So, I want to find the optimal threshold to separate the classes based on this single variable.
I thought maybe SVM, but I don't understand the results for a single predictor..
Then I thought about using a
varying threshold on the independent variable, get the prediction performance (true positives, false negatives) for each threshold, plot the roc curve and check for the best performance (and the respective threshold).

Is this overcomplicated? Is there a statistical test for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that I have a continuous varisble, measured on a set of subjects, and a label (0 unhealthy,1 healthy) for each subject.

- I ended up finding the maximum, minimum and an appropriate step for each of my variables (minimum variation expected to be relevant).
- Generated a vector such as: thresholds =[min:step:max]
  -Then, iterated over the values in thresholds in a for loop.
  At each time generating a binary vector with labels based on variable>threshold.
- Then calculated the confusion matrix and a performance metric.
- Finally, found the maximum performance achieved and the respective threshold value. Indicating that the threshold is the optimal separation based on classification performance for the current dataset.